# Como fusionar elementos tipo string de listas anidadas python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.7

> bueno lo que quiero hacer es poder fusionar todos los string de cada lista anidada

```
lista = [['4', '8', '9', '2', '9', '7'], ['8', '5', '8', '3', '7'], ['0', '0', '3', '9']]
```

> de tal forma que me quede ['489297','85837','0039']

> es posible hacer esto con un for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión de comprensión de listas:

```
resultado = [ "".join(sublista) for sublista in lista ]
```

Esto es equivalente a un `for` explícito como el siguiente:

```
resultado = []
for sublista in lista:
   resultado.append("".join(sublista))
```

En ambos casos `join()` es quien concatena todos los elementos de una sublista en una sola cadena. En este caso he usado `"".join()` para indicar que a la hora de concatenar use una cadena vacía (`""`) como separador. Si hubieras puesto por ejemplo `"-".join(sublista)` el resultado sería algo como `"4-8-9-2-9-7"`, etc.